# Copy array of cell values to range in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, copy, formulas

I am trying to copy a sheet to a new workbook with only values, not formulas. I need one column to retain formulas.

It may not be the best method, but I am trying to copy the formulas to a variant array, then copy the values, then add the array of formulas to the new worksheet.

I am using the following code but getting an error. "Run Time Error: 1004 Application defined or object defined error.

```
Set wbNew = Workbooks.Open(NewName)

Dim Colm As Variant
Dim Frange As Range

Colm = wbNew.Sheets(wsName).Range("F1:F100").Formula

wbNew.Sheets(wsName).UsedRange.Value = wbNew.Sheets(wsName).UsedRange.Value

Set Frange = wbNew.Sheets(wsName).Range("F1:F100")

Set Frange = Frange.Resize(UBound(Colm), 1)

Frange.Value = Colm
```

Comment: (a) You have never assigned a value to `wsName` and `NewName` (but maybe that is just due to having posted something that isn't a MCVE?) (b) Which line gives the error?  (c) Code worked for me once I gave `wsName` and `NewName` values, and gave different errors to the one you are getting if I hadn't.

Comment: I agree with @YowE3K everything should work, as long as the `NewName` and `wsName` are correct. This line does nothing: `Set Frange = Frange.Resize(UBound(Colm), 1)`.  `Frange` is already `UBound(Colm)` rows by 1 column.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
Set wbNew = Workbooks.Open(NewName)

Dim Colm As Variant
Dim Frange As Range

Set Frange = wbNew.Sheets(wsName).Range("F1:F100")

Colm = Frange.Formula

With wbNew.Sheets(wsName).UsedRange
    .Value = .Value
End With

Frange.Value = Colm
```